# what is the proper regular expression for this example?

Tags: java, regex

Which regular expression in java can do these conversions?

```
"1.54.0.21" to "01540021"
```

or

```
"33.5.10.6" to "33051006"
```

I need to replace `.#` with `0#` and `.##` with `##`

Comment: What's wrong with `String#replaceAll("\\.", "");`?

Comment: no I need to replace `.#` with `0#` and `.##` with `##`

Comment: @MadProgrammer note the extra 0s.

Comment: Ah, so they're padding :P

Comment: So, `String.split` then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like...

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(8);
String input = "1.54.0.21";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group();
    if (group.length() < 2) {
        output.append("0");
    }
    output.append(group);
}

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

Which outputs...

```
1.54.0.21
01540021
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Regex :

http://rextester.com/LGXETU62790

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str1 = "33.5.9.6";
    String str2 = "1.54.0.21";
    System.out.println(transform(str1));
    System.out.println(transform(str2));
}

private static String transform(String str){
    String[] splitted = str.split("\\.");
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : splitted){
        build.append(String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(s)));
    }
    return build.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getToken(String elem) {
    return (elem.size() == 1) ? ("0" + elem) : elem;
}

String[] a = "1.54.0.21".split("\\.");
String o = "", e;
int i = 0, len = a.size();
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    o = o + getToken(a[i]);
}
System.out.println(o);  //01540021
```

Answer (score 0):

The only functionality of a regular expression is to match a certain pattern of characters inside a string (or multiline strings).
    A regular expression can be used in a find and replace Pattern but only to find the strings you are interested in.  When they are found , a Split(), Remove(), Replace(), function will better do it's purpose.

```
I recommend you : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
```

This is an online tool for matching strings with regular expression, and also learning the patterns.